# How to calculate averages by date/month/year from Array in Swift3

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift3

I have an Array of Dictionaries.

The Dictionary is like `["date":"2017-07-03T10:12:00", "amount":2.1]`.

**EDIT**

Let's say, I have the following array.

```
let dic1 = ["date":"2017-07-03T10:12:00", "amount":2.0]
let dic2 = ["date":"2017-07-03T11:15:03", "amount":4.0]
let dic3 = ["date":"2017-07-03T17:05:04", "amount":1.0]
let dic4 = ["date":"2017-07-04T09:05:03", "amount":3.0]
let dic5 = ["date":"2017-07-04T12:01:22", "amount":5.0]
let dic6 = ["date":"2017-07-04T19:01:01", "amount":2.0]
let array = [dic1, dic2, dic3, dic4, dic5, dic6]
```

Now I'm trying to calculate the following result from Array.

```
"date":"2017-07-03", "average":3.5
"date":"2017-07-04", "average":5.0
"date":"2017-07", "average":2.82..
"date":"2017", "average":2.82..
```

I could get the average of all data with the following code but I'm stuck now.

```
let average = array.flatMap({ $0["amount"] as? Double }).reduce(0, +) / Double(array.count)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to find out `average` of some `Date` values? There is nothing like this in theory. Update your question with sample input and output.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion using a custom struct including a date formatter to convert the ISO8601 string to `Date`

```
struct Item {
    let date : Date
    let amount : Double

    static let dateFormatter : ISO8601DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        formatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate, .withTime, .withColonSeparatorInTime]
        return formatter
    }()

    init(date: String, amount: Double) {
        self.date = Item.dateFormatter.date(from: date)!
        self.amount = amount
    }
}
```

Populate the array

```
let items = [Item(date : "2017-07-03T10:12:00", amount :2.0),
             Item(date : "2017-07-03T11:15:03", amount :4.0),
             Item(date : "2017-07-03T17:05:04", amount :1.0),
             Item(date : "2017-07-04T09:05:03", amount :3.0),
             Item(date : "2017-07-04T12:01:22", amount :5.0),
             Item(date : "2017-07-04T19:01:01", amount :2.0)]
```

Create a function to take the array and specific date components as parameters

```
func average(of items: [Item], matching components: DateComponents) -> Double
{
    let filteredDates = items.filter { Calendar.current.date($0.date, matchesComponents: components) }
    return filteredDates.map{ $0.amount }.reduce(0.0, +) / Double(filteredDates.count)
}
```

Now filter the items by date components and return the average value

```
average(of: items, matching: DateComponents(year: 2017, month: 7, day: 3))
average(of: items, matching: DateComponents(year: 2017, month: 7, day: 4))
average(of: items, matching: DateComponents(year: 2017, month: 7))
average(of: items, matching: DateComponents(year: 2017))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your array and calculate the average of the filtered values. This example is for the year 2017, but you can apply the same method for other values as well.

```
let filteredArray = array.filter { Calendar.current.component(.year, from: $0) == 2017 }
let average = (filteredArray.map { $0 as? Double ?? 0 }).reduce(0, +) / Double(filteredArray.count)
```